# How to develop a theme while having another show up

Tags: themes

The title is the question : How to develop a theme while having another show up

I already have a DB and a theme.... i like, when log as admin see another theme... just for the time making it clean and final... and then, remove the old one and have the new one able to be see for everybody...

any plugin that do that ?

---

some research and result : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-test-drive/
 and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nkthemeswitch/

not sure what it's worth....

Comment: Guys, come on! Four answers and the only up vote is from me? [Vote Early, Vote Often!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this one a while ago and it worked. Hasn't been updated in a while...but should still work.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/parallels-themes-switcher

Answer (score 2):

Perhpas you can keep the theme live you want others to see and for your self use url theme switcher to switch theme like : `

> `http://www.you_site.com/index.php?wptheme=WordPress+Classic`

replace www.you_site.com with your own site url.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12931/dynamic-template-serving-change-theme-root-using-add-filter-from-current-theme)

```
<?php
/* SWAP THEME ACCORDING TO USER */
function wpse50258_change_theme( $template = '' ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    if ( $current_user->user_login === 'YOUR-USER-NAME' ) {
        $template = 'twentyten';
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter('template', 'wpse50258_change_theme');
add_filter('option_template', 'wpse50258_change_theme');
add_filter('option_stylesheet', 'wpse50258_change_theme');
```

[UPDATE]

PS: this only works if fired from a plugin, not from functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the site to your computer (running XAMPP or some other local server software) and work locally while developing the new theme. When it's tested and ready, upload the new theme and make the switch.

Alternately, copy the site to a subfolder and use that or a subdomain like dev.yoursite.com to develop. Usually you'll want to use a plugin like Maintenance Mode to hide the dev site.

I use BackupBuddy for moving the site down and back up. It's a bit faster than a manual move, but neither is particularly hard.