# Display a different theme for not logged-in users

Tags: theme-development, themes, filters, hooks, switch-theme

Based on [answers like this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50233/how-to-develop-a-theme-while-having-another-show-up?noredirect=1&lq=1), I made a small plugin to display a theme displaying a "Coming soon" theme, whilst our team of editors can fill in the final theme.

It worked yesterday, but today, even though I'm logged in, I only see the "waiting" theme. 
I logged out and logged back in, but still, I'm seeing the "waiting" theme, as if the `is_user_logged_in()` function returned false. Are these hooks too early to check for user authentification?

```
<?php

add_filter('template', 'pxln_change_theme');
add_filter('stylesheet', 'pxln_change_theme');

function pxln_change_theme($theme) {    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $theme = 'waiting';
    }
    return $theme;
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer. Tested it locally, and it works. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

[Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), unlike actions, don't run at a specific moment, but when the function they are attached too, is called. The template-filter is called from [`get_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template/) and the stylesheet-filter from [`get_stylesheet`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet/).

Typically, these functions are called to enqueue styles and scripts using `wp_enqueue-scripts`, an [action that takes place after](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) the current user has been set. However, it is not uncommon to see these functions also called from a function that is attached to `after_setup_theme`, which is fired before the current user has been set.

So, you will have to check your theme for the use of `get_template` and `get_stylesheet` (or a function that uses them, which you can find under 'used by' in the links above). Then check if the function is attached to a hook that is too early.

Comment: can't agree with the first words of the answer. Actions are filters thta do not return value, that is whole of the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a probable cause. My "main" theme uses `get_template_part` and `get_stylesheet_uri`extensively, so that must be it. I just wished there 'd be a cross-theme, reliable solution. :(

Answer (score 2):

Try hooking on all these:

(But I guess you'd have to do it from a plugin, since doing it from theme `functions.php` might be too late).

E.g.:

```
/*
Plugin Name: test
Description: switchtest
Version: 0.1.0
*/

add_filter( 'template', 'yourthing_switch_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_template', 'yourthing_switch_theme' );
add_filter( 'option_stylesheet', 'yourthing_switch_theme' );
add_filter( 'pre_option_stylesheet', 'yourthing_switch_theme' );

function yourthing_switch_theme( $theme )
{
   if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $theme;
   }
   else {
      return 'waiting';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Unfortunately, that does not solve the issue.

Comment: just tried the updated version (finally managed to find time to install wp locally), and works as advertised. :)